# How to pass func with any return type as parameter into another function?

Tags: go, generics, func

```
func F(f func()interface{})interface{} {
    return f()
}

func one() int {
    return 1
}
type A struct {}
func two() A {
  return A{}
}
func main() {

    a := F(one)
    b := F(two)
}
```

The code above will fail with error

```
cannot use one (type func() int) as type func() interface {} in argument to F
cannot use two (type func() A) as type func() interface {} in argument to F
```

My question is how to pass a func with any possible output as a parameter?

Comment: You need to type the other function to return an empty interface. This thing always gets me in Go, I still don't really understand why it was designed like this. I understand your line of thinking, int should be covered under empty interface and therefore be valid as return type, but it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A value of type `int` can be assigned to an `interface{}` variable; a value of type `func() int` can **not** be assigned to a value of type `func() interface{}`. This is true with any version of Go.

Though, what you are attempting to do can be achieved with Go 1.18, where you can easily parametrize the function with `T any` — where `any` is an alias of `interface{}`:

```
func Callf[T any](f func() T) T {
    return f()
}

func one() int {
    return 1
}

type A struct {}
func two() A {
  return A{}
}

func main() {
    a := Callf(one)
    b := Callf(two)

    fmt.Println(a) // 1
    fmt.Println(b) // {}
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/zCB5VUhQpXE